# Optimising a function to work for multiple names elements

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write this into a function that would do the same thing (ie fade in/out) for listSub1 and routeA as listSub2 and routeB, without writing them out manually. Ie it would work for listSub3 and routeC, 4 and D, 5 and E etc and all be included in one function? Something that says listSub(1+) and route(A+)? I dunno. I can't find anything about this online, probably because I don't know what to look for. Thanks!

```
  $(".listSub1").hover(function(){
          $(".routeA").stop().fadeToggle(500);
      },
      function(){
          $(".routeA").stop().fadeToggle(500);
      });
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to learn about arrays and loops. Or alternatively CSS selectors.

Comment: I'll look into it- thanks!

Comment: Update your design in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you assign them two class like listSub, listSub1 and listSub and listSub2.
And then add event to listSub and check if it is which listSub and then do your thing.

```
$(".listSub").hover(function(){
      // Get the second class  
      $(".route"+getSecondClass(this)).stop().fadeToggle(500);
  });

function getSecondClass(this){
    // get second class
    // return A if 1, etc
}
```

Easy thing would be to apply event on each class with for loop but this is more flexible way to do it.

Comment: I might be missing something as I don't quite follow this, but wouldn't this require route and listsub to be classes of the same element? They are different unrelated elements, not parent or child.

Comment: the element you are adding class listsub to, just add the class listSubX too. In  hover handler just check if the hovered element has a class name listSubX.